# App Engine: Best way to check for updates to data in data store, while avoiding datastore writes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a large amount of entities (products) in my  datastore which come from a external data source. I want to check them for updates daily.

Some items are already updated because the application fetched them directly. Some are newly inserted and don´t need updates.

For ones which have not been fetched I have cron jobs running. I use the Python API.

At the moment I do the following.

I have a field

```
dateupdated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I can then use

```
query = dbmodel.product.all()
query.filter('dateupdated <', newdate)
query.order('dateupdated')        
results = query.fetch(limit=mylimit, offset=myoffset)
```

to pick the oldest entries and schedule them for update. I used the Task Queue with custom task names to make sure each product update is only run once a day.

The problem is, that I need to update the field dateupdated, which means a datastore write, even if a product´s data was not changed, just to keep track of the update process.

This consumes lots of ressources (CPU hours, Datastore API calls, etc.).

Is there a better way to perform such a task and avoid the unnecessary datastore writes?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure why you were updating the dateupdated field? or why you were not storing the "last date we ran the check" and using that rather than via some offset, but either way, I think cursors are what you are looking for.

Comment: If you run your query once a day, you don't need to filter by when you last checked, do you? All products will have been checked at least a day ago, when you last ran the process. In any case, writing a few timestamps to records is unlikely to impose a significant CPU time burden, unless you're dealing with millions of products.

Comment: @Nick Johnson I filter to exclude items which have already been updated by other processes or are new. I could also skip this, as the taskqueue would not allow me to schedule more than one product update per day (using custom names). The question is: what is more efficient? Anyway, my understanding was that using something like `myproduct = product.get_by_key_name(productkey)
myproduct.dateupdated = datetime.datetime.now()
product.put(myproduct)`is the same as storing the whole entitiy again? Or are you suggesting that it would only update the changed field and consume less cpu?

Comment: @Abilo Yes, it writes the whole entity - but that's not going to be a significant drain on resources unless you're updating millions of products daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [cursors](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors)

By ordering a query by `dateupdated` and then storing a cursor after you have processed your entities, you can re-run the same query later to get only the items updated after your last query.

So, given a class like

```
class MyEntity(db.model):
    dateupdated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

You could setup a handler to be run as a task like:

```
class ProcessNewEntities(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        """Run via a task to process batches of 'batch_size' 
        recently updated entities"""
        # number of eneities to process per task execution
        batch_size = 100
        # build the basic query
        q = MyEntity.all().order("dateupdated")
        # use a cursor?
        cursor = self.request.get("cursor")
        if cursor:
            q.with_cursor(cursor)
        # fetch the batch
        entities = q.fetch(batch_size)
        for entity in entities:
            # process the entity
            do_your_processing(entity)
        # queue up the next task to process the next 100
        # if we have no more to process then delay this task 
        # for a while so that it doesn't hog the application
        delay = 600 if len(entities)<batch_size else 0
        taskqueue.add(
            url='/tasks/process_new_entities', 
            params={'cursor': q.cursor()},
            countdown=delay)
```

and then you just need to trigger the start of the task execution like:

```
def start_processing_entities():
    taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/process_new_entities')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailled description, that looks promising. The only issue I see is, that I would not be able to use a filter like   `query.filter('dateupdated <', newdate)` with it. But I am sure there are ways to work around it.